# Aligning columns with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am shure someone asked this before, but I was unable to come up with a good formulation to search for :(. Anyway.

Have a look the following code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span6">
            <div class="well">HELOO WORLD</div>
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
            <div class="well">
                some very long text here
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
            <div class="well">HELOO WORLD</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/1505/) a jsfillde. Is there any way I can pull up the third span to come directly after the first span?

Thanks,
Niklas

Comment: Mind this: correct tag for your question is [tag:twitter-bootstrap], not just [tag:bootstrap].

Comment: Have a look at CSS' `column-count`. Maybe that's what you're looking for.

Comment: `column-count` is kind of it, but this also wraps in the middle of a div within a child div.

Comment: Yeah, while I was testing, this happened to me too. I recommend trying it outside of JSfiddle. Not whether whether it has to do with it's limiations in width/height.

Comment: I did. It behaved the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Put](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/1506/) the third div into first column:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span6">
            <div class="well">HELOO WORLD</div>
            <div class="well">HELOO WORLD</div>
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
            <div class="well">
                some very long text here
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought about that, but when doing this programmatically, how can I balance the columns? Say every second entry is long then the colums become largely unbalanced.

Comment: This turns your question into completely different one. For that case you should use jQuery Masonry (IE 8) or CSS Masonry (based on `columns`).

Answer (score 0):

You can change the CSS to alternate wich way each span6 div floats. Since the default float is left, just apply float right to the alternate divs. This

```
[class="span6"]:nth-of-type(even) {
    float: right;
}
```